# How to insert "for" in ternary + arrow notation

Tags: javascript

I learning JS, still at the beginning of the journey..

I want to understand now to express a for, nested in a function, but following the arrows + ternary format.

I have tried placing the `for` in several parts of the code, but it did not accept it. I manage to write it without considering the `for`, selecting the array i wanna see. But this is not what I want..

`let tester = (name,prop) => contacts[0]["firstName"] == name ? contacts[0][prop] : "error!";`

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function tester(name,prop)
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length;i++)
    {
      if (contacts[i]["firstName"]==name) 
      {
        return contacts[i][prop]
      }
      else
      {
        return "error"
      } 
    }
  }
```

I would like to understand where do I relate the `for` using ternary & arrows operators.

Comment: your loop is wrong, `i` start an stop at zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas have a form that is similar to `function` that can be inlined in the same way as the implied-`return` form:

```
let tester = (name, prop) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i]["firstName"] == name) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        }
    }
    return "error";
};
```

But really, you may want to consider using `Array`'s collection methods, in this case [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
let tester = (name, prop) => {
    let results = contacts.find(item => item["firstName"] == name);
    return results === undefined ? "error" : results[prop];
};
```

Comment: It's still going to just going to loop once and exit, though.

Comment: @VLAZ As appears to be the asker's intent.

Comment: ...or their mistake. I'm not really sure what the intent is.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, I see now. I thought there was something weird but just chalked it up to newbs being newbs without really thinking about it.